# CurlFile() results in submission of JSON string instead of file data

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I'm using `CurlFile()` to `POST` a file to our server using `cURL`.  However, I'm not receiving the actual file; I'm just receiving what looks to be a JSON representation of the object created by `CurlFile()`...

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
$args['thumbnail'] = new CurlFile('/home/xyz/public_html/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/11814129_M.jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image.jpg');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
```

What is received on the server:

```
array(6) {
  ...
  ["thumbnail"]=>
  string(133) "{"name":"\/home\/xyz\/public_html\/wp\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/03\/11814129_M.jpg","mime":"image\/jpeg","postname":"image.jpg"}"
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Looks like it's a problem with the Facebook SDK I'm using and not PHP/cURL:

> Sadly while Curl was happy with this, the Facebook PHP SDK (v3.2.2)
>   was not. It turns out the SDK will turn ANY value you send it in that
>   params array into a string.

More info: https://philsturgeon.uk/php/2013/08/29/curlfile-and-the-facebook-sdk-in-php-55/